# Freeform unsubscribe and redirect non admin users away from admin area

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, plugin-solspacecalendar, dashboard

Good Evening all,

I have a site that lets users subscribe/unsubscribe using Freeforms Stripe payments.

Everything is working fine, except for when the user unsubscribes, the link that is required is within the Craft Dashboard, therefore the user has to have a basic amount of panel access, which I want to avoid if possible, however as a fix, is there any way of redirecting non admin users away from the login/dashboard if they type /admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. This is a known issue and we will have a fix for this available in Freeform 3.10.8 in a few days (February 15-16, 2021). :)